# CSS zoom property

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css, zooming

[Sitepoint reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/zoom) says

> Internet Explorer for Windows versions
>   5.5 and above support the non-standard property zoom, which sets the
>   magnification scale of an element.
>   There’s no CSS3 equivalent to this
>   property (as yet).

How can I achieve this zoom effect in standard browsers? Any jQuery plugins available?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The CSS3 equivalent is in the [CSS 2D Transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/) module, in particular `transform: scale()`.

Because this module is still at Working Draft stage, you'll need browser-specific prefixes:

```
transform: scale(2);
-moz-transform: scale(2);
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
-o-transform: scale(2);
```

You may also need `transform-origin` (and browser-specific versions) to make it behave the same way as `zoom`, and you'll have to be careful to target `zoom` only at IE, because WebKit supports both `transform` *and* `zoom` so would double-scale.

Comment: IE9 seems to require -ms-transform property name.

Answer (score 3):

To complete the answer of scale transformations: why you not addressing IE as well? There is a specific `-ms-zoom` property, which will work in IE only: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531189(v=vs.85).aspx